# How to split a string on a character that occurs more than once inside the string

Tags: python, string, parsing, indexing, split

I am having a some logic issues attempting to parse a string into two fields. Name and Version.  I have been splitting on "/" and it works very well for strings that have only one "/" in them. for example:

```
strString = someName/A
nameVer = strString .split('/')
name = nameVer[0]
ver = nameVer[1]
```

this returns name=someName and ver=A. Which is what i want. The problem is when i have more than one "/" in the string. Particularly this 3 cases:

```
Part ="someName//" #Expected output: name=someName ver=\
Part1="some/Name/A" #Expected output:name=some/Name ver=A
Part2="some/Name//" #Expected output:name=some/Name ver=/
```

Both the name and version can be or contain "/"'s. I have tried many things including keeping track of the indexes of the "/" and grabbing whats in between. In some cases I have also added brackets to the string ("[some/Name//]") so i can index the first and last char  of the string.  Any help with this is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There's not going to be any general way to parse strings containing `/` that are also separated by `/`.  You'd need to have more information.  Like, how do *you* know which `/` is supposed to be the delimiter and which are part of the names?

Comment: In the first line of code, the string should be quoted. Also, the expected output of Part should be `ver=/`, not `ver=\`, as backslash doesn't appear in the first string.

Comment: I missed the second part of the question and agree with @BrenBarn - it's too vague. I suggest that the OP comes up with a unique string to delimit the name from the version.

Comment: Also then name and version can both be "/"...really?!

Comment: yes i know its odd. the name will always have a unique value and MIGHT contain a "/". the version can be a "/" all by itself.  My initial response is YES I wish there was a different delimiter but I cannot change that because I am parsing the output of a logfile.

Comment: Can the version *contain* slashes, or can it just *be* a single slash?  If it can't contain multiple slashes, then you can just specifically check if the last character is a slash.

Comment: the version can contain slashes or be a single slash. both "a/" and "/" would be a valid version.

Answer (score 1):

Following some useful comments by BrenBarn and sr2222, I suggest the following solutions.

The OP should either

- Make sure that the version string does not contain any '/' characters, and then use `rsplit` as suggested by sr2222

**or**

- Choose a different delimiter for for the name-version division

A solution that ignores the last character (such that it can be assigned to the `ver` variable) would be

```
ind = Part[:-1].rindex('/')
name = Part[:ind+1]
ver = Part[ind+1:]
```

On the OPs inputs this produces the desired output.

Comment: Or just use `rsplit` or `rpartition`.

Comment: This works if it's always the last `/` that separates the name from the version, but it's not clear from the OP's description if that's the case.

Comment: Ahh oops, right you are @sr2222 - you should post as a separate answer and have that accepted.

Comment: Also - I missed the second part of the question and agree with @BrenBarn - it's too vague. I suggest that the OP comes up with a unique string to delimit the name from the version.

Comment: Like I said a different delimiter would be my first choice but i cant change it.  If I could get a snippet or two that handles one or two of the cases I mentioned i would be happy.

Comment: @Dean0 - I think my last addition does perform as you requested for the cases you presented. Just not sure if it will be much use for more general cases...

Comment: thankyou everyone for your input. I will run a few test cases on the snippets provided and post my final solution tomorrow afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

If any instance of the separator might be doing the separating, there are too many choices. Take your last example, `some/name//`. Which of the three slashes is the
separator? The string can be parsed, in order, as `("some", "name//")`,
as `("some/name", "/")`, or as `("some/name/", "")`.

What to do? Let's say the version is necessarily non-empty (ruling out option 3),
and otherwise the name part should be maximal. If you like these rules,
here's a regexp that will do the job: `r'^(.*)/(.+)$'`. You can use it like this:

```
name, ver = re.match(r'^(.*)/(.+)$', "some/name/").groups()
```

Here's what it does:

```
>>> re.match(r'^(.*)/(.+)$', "name//").groups()
('name', '/')
>>> re.match(r'^(.*)/(.+)$', "some/name/a").groups()
('some/name', 'a')
>>> re.match(r'^(.*)/(.+)$', "some/name//").groups()
('some/name', '/')
>>> re.match(r'^(.*)/(.+)$', "some/name/").groups()
('some', 'name/')
```

In short, it splits on the last slash that has *something* after it (possibly a final slash). If you don't like this approach, you'll need to provide more detail on what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

For the cases you've posted, this would work:

```
if part.endswith('//'):
    name, ver = part[:-2], '/’
else:
    name, ver = part.rsplit(’/’, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I made that handles just about every case.  The only cases that it does not handle is when the name and version is ambiguous and you cannot tell if a "/" is apart of the name or ver. Thank you for everyone's input.

```
Part ="[0717_PFM1//]"
Part1="[0717_PFM1/A]"  #generic case
Part2="[0717/_PFM1/A]" 
Part3="[07/17/_PFM1//]" #Test case below
#Part3="[0717/_PFM1//B]" #Not working, ambigous: cant tell if the ending slash is part     of name or ver

import re
lastCharIndex = Part3.index(']')
list1 =[]
counter = 0
numberOfSlashes = Part3.count("/")
if numberOfSlashes > 1:
   nameVer = Part3.split("/")
   name1, ver1 = re.match(r'^(.*)/(.+)$', Part3).groups()

   if nameVer[2].strip("]") or ver1.strip("]") == "":
      ver = "/"
   else:
      ver = nameVer[2].strip("]")

   name = nameVer[0].strip('[')
   if len(name1)>len(name):
      name = name1

   if len(ver1) > len(ver):
      ver = ver1

   name = name.rstrip("/")
else:

   nameVer = Part3.split("/")
   name, ver = nameVer[0], nameVer[1]

print "name",name.strip('['), "ver",ver.strip(']')
```